# Where can I find a good translation of the Sulabha Janaka Samvada of the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, history, bhishma, janaka, yudhisthira

Sulabha Janaka Samvada is a conversation between the female saint Sulabha and king Janaka. This conversation is revealed by Bhishma to Yudhisthira in the Shanti Parva of the Mahabharata.

The most famous [translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c020.htm) of the Sulabha Janaka Samvada is by Kisari Mohan Ganguli. With due respect to the author, it is very difficult to read (in arcane English) and is at some places wrong.

Where can I find a good translation for the same?

Comment: Did you see Debroy's translation?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I did not come across his translation. And, hi, long time. :)

Comment: Hi... I mailed you all the different versions of Mahabhartha i have including Debroy's translation.

Answer (score 2):

I found an excellent translation by Ram Narayan Dutt Shastri, but it is in Hindi:

http://archive.org/details/mahabharat05ramauoft

I had to work on a project where the conversation had to be translated. Here is my humble attempt at an English translation (uploaded on the *Academia* website):

http://www.academia.edu/27543247/English_translation_of_the_Sulabha_Janaka_Samvada_found_in_the_Shanti_Parva_of_the_Mahabharata